# How to get a Wacom Graphire4 to work in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, wacom, configure, graphics-tablet

I have been stuggling to get my elderly Wacom tablet to work properly in Artful. Goggling has yielded plenty of old, but not particularly useful info. So, has anyone been able to get a Wacom Graphire4 tablet to work properly in Artful?

Here is what I have done on both a Desktop using a modern i7 processor and running the 64 bit version of Ubuntu 17.10 and on an older SONY laptop running the 32 bit version (an upgrade from Ubuntu Gnome 17.04).

I am in an xorg session.

```
rquint@Kovalevskaia:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

In Settings|Devices|Wacom Tablet|Tablet it shows a Wacom Graphire4 4x5, but any settings I change have no effect, the puck just works as a simple mouse in relative mode. In Settings|Devices|Wacom Tablet|Stylus the stylus is not recognized.

All the required packages are installed.

When I go into a terminal I get

```
rquint@Kovalevskaia:~$ xsetwacom --list
Wacom Graphire4 4x5 Pen stylus      id: 10  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Graphire4 4x5 Pad pad         id: 11  type: PAD       
Wacom Graphire4 4x5 Pen eraser      id: 14  type: ERASER    
Wacom Graphire4 4x5 Pen cursor      id: 15  type: CURSOR
```

but when I try to set a value (say for one of the buttons on the tablet) I get

```
rquint@Kovalevskaia:~$ xsetwacom set "Graphire4 4x5 pad" Button 2 "key ctrl z"
Cannot find device 'Graphire4 4x5 pad'.
```

What next?

Answer (score 0):

The control panel not recognizing your stylus seems to be a bug. I don't see anything about it in GNOME's bug tracker, however, so they may not be aware of it.

As for using xsetwacom, you must provide it with the full device name (i.e., the first column of the output of `xsetwacom --list`). In your specific case, you will need to use "Wacom Graphire4 4x5 Pad pad" rather than "Graphire4 4x5 pad".

Comment: GNOME bug filed at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=793499

Comment: Using the full device name "Wacom Graphire4 4x5 Pad pad" changed the response to nothing, but otherwise had no effect. I've also found that if I play with the Input Device settings inside GIMP I can get the stylus to work within GIMP, but with inconsistent behaviour (pressure works sometimes, the mouse moves the cursor but doesn't work with the paint or pencil selected).